# outlook add-in not loading on windows or Ios but loading on web

Tags: xml, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have created an add-in which I need to use while composing a meeting on Outlook. It is working fine when using it with Outlook for web, but it's not showing up on the Windows or iOS versions of Outlook.

When I first tested the compatibility using the Message Read scenario, it was loading on all the versions of Outlook.

Below is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
    <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
    <Id>329ebc3b-94bb-4994-9865-279d69fe273c</Id>
    <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>test</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="testmail-23" />
    <Description DefaultValue="This will create a meeting in timu"/>
    <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
    <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/support.html" />
    <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <!--End Basic Settings. -->
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox" />
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" /></Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    <VersionOverrides 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                    <!-- Message Read -->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                        <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                            <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                                        <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
                <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
                <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
                <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Display all properties"/>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Which version/build numbers of Outlook are you testing against?

Comment: I installed your manifest (without making any changes to it), launched a new Meeting, and your add-in shows up in my ribbon as "Display all properties", in a chunk named "My Add-in Group".

Since you have only the DesktopFormFactor, your add-in will only show up on Outlook on a Desktop. For iOS (mobile), see the MobileFormFactor documentation at https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/mobileformfactor.

Comment: Now I'm able to see the add in my add-in group.  @MarcLaFleur could help me how to check the outlook requirement version?

Comment: Each Outlook client surfaces it's version/build number differently. See for https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-version-of-Outlook-do-I-have-b3a9568c-edb5-42b9-9825-d48d82b2257c for details by platform.